# Firestore error Function not found error: Name: [exists]

Tags: firebase-security

Given the following `firestore rules`

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    function isSuperAdmin() {
      return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/super_admins/$(request.auth.uid));
    }

    match /projects/{anyProject} {
      match /tasks/{anyTask} {
        allow update: if isSuperAdmin();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to run in the simulator a simple update causing the following error -
`Error running simulation — Error: simulator.rules line [20], column [14]. Function not found error: Name: [exists].`

[image: exists function not found]

[image: The update]

Comment: I assume this is a temporary bug

Comment: any update on this by chance? Having the same issue

Comment: I believe it is randomly happens and get fixed - Something is missing on the firebase team unit testing and I guess it just breaks some days.
Perhaps wait a few days OR report a bug

Comment: Seems to be bugged again/still. A workaround I ended up using was: `get(PATH) != null`